# How to know how many lines to batch write python

Tags: python, file-io

I am reading in a file with strings and outputting a file based on it, with some modifications. Is it faster to read one line, make the modifications, and output it immediately, or is it better to read several lines, make the modifications and batchwrite them at once. If its faster to write them in batches, how do I optimize the size of the batch to be fastest, as I imagine that storing a string or list millions of lines long could slow things down unnecessarily.

Comment: Why not try it different ways and see for yourself?

Comment: http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf will help heavily

Comment: Off-topic: too broad. Answers could get way too theoretical and hand-wavy to be of any use. You'll have to profile it yourself like the first commenter said -- there's a lot of scenarios here.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it one by one, your code will be much cleaner and easier to reason about that way. By default all IO to files is buffered anyway, which means actual writes will only be flushed when the underlying buffer is full

Answer (score 0):

Write some code to test it!

As I said in a comment on your previous question, your OS will do buffering and caching, so not every read or write call will result in a disk access. However, system calls *are* slower than list manipulations, so you will get better speed working with reasonable sized blocks of data, eg 64kB. Larger blocks, up to 1MB may be slightly faster, depending on the device (eg traditional magnetic HD vs SSD), but IME 64kB is generally adequate.

But definitely do some tests before you go about major restructuring of your existing code. Determine that I/O is actually a bottleneck for your program before you bother trying to improve I/O speed. As Knuth said, premature optimization is the root of all evil.